# Как интегрировать бд в веб проект?

Tags: java, spring, web-apps

Нужно интегрировать в проект бд (derby) и встроить в war-архив вместе в веб проектом. Как это можно сделать?

Я использую tomcat 7, hibernate.

настройки hibernate:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:derby:**db_name**;
jdbc.username=**user_name**
jdbc.password=**password**
```

Answer (score 1):

Собственно нужно создать бин dataSource, который и будет вашим "окном" в базу данных. На примере Оракла:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:bd"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>
```

Тут же можно создать jdbcTemplate на основе этого датасорса, создав бин типа org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate с конструктором параметризованным ссылкой на dataSource:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Для Derby, думаю, вполне подойдет org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

До кучи вот вам еще ссылка на примеры: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/